# Show that the relaxation of the clique formulation for the simple circular interval packing problem does not always describe the integer hull.

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

Today I have found this problem that really intrigues me while studying for an optimization exam:

**Show that the relaxation of the clique formulation for the simple circular interval packing problem does not always describe the integer hull.**

Here the 'clique formulation' denotes the inequality formulation of the linear problem that requires all maximal cliques $S$ of nodes in a graph $G = (V,E)$ to fulfill the following:

$$x(E[S])$$

And 'simple circular interval packing problem' denotes the following probem:  The intervals are a consecutive subset of the circumference of a circle, and for any angle there can be at most
one selected interval covering that angle.

Now in an attempt to solve the problem I have tied to draw several examples of such graphs. My main idea is to construct a graph that does not contain a maximal clique of size larger than 2 but that still prohibits some combinations of intervals in a maximal solution as this property would then not be covered by the relaxation... But I have severe problems finding such an example if there even exists one.

**Edit:** I have an idea. How about I take just one interval $x_1$ that goes around the circle more than once covering for example an angle of $3\pi$. Then an optimal integral solution is the empty set but an optimal solution to the linear relaxation would be $\frac{2}{3} x_1$. Does that make any sense?

Thanks in advance for your help.